# React componentDidMount - Cannot read property of undefined -

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React application which fetches data from an API and then presents various views on the data to users.  I obviously don't want to keep going back to the API for this data so I store it in context and filter it as required.

I decide whether to make a call in `componentDidUpdate` as below:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log("TABLE IS UPDATED.." + this.context.ownedCards[0].brand);
    console.log("OWNED CARDS" + JSON.stringify(this.context.ownedCards));
    if (
    // if the array that stores the result of API call is empty, make a fresh call for the data
      this.context.ownedCards.length < 1
    ) {
      this.context.loadOwnedCardData(this.props.path);
    } else if (this.context.wantedCards.length < 1) {
      this.context.loadWantedCardData(this.props.path);
    }
  }
```

However, in order to make this function correctly I need to be able to check a value in the `this.context.ownedCards` array. My second console.log `console.log("OWNED CARDS" + JSON.stringify(this.context.ownedCards));` shows me the object fine

```
[{"_id":{"$oid":"5f94118b32d764f7ad2c64c3"},"card_id":"cardid-1602670562011","brand":"Contenders","card_number":{"$numberDouble":"161"},"career_stage":"Rookie Card","forTrade":"","image_path":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/","manufacturer":"Panini","number":{"$numberDouble":"0"},"player":"Kelvin Harmon","print_run":{"$numberDouble":"39"},"purchase_date":"Sun Sep 13 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020","series":"Rookie Ticket Autographs","status":"Own","team":"Washington Football Team","type":"Auto","user":"jinky32@gmail.com","variation":"Base","year":"2019","userName":"jinky32"},{"_id":{"$oid":"5f94118b32d764f7ad2c64ed"},"card_id":"cardid-1602670562493","brand":"National Treasures","card_number":{"$numberDouble":"107"},"career_stage":"Rookie Card","forTrade":"No","image_path":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/","manufacturer":"Panini","number":{"$numberDouble":"60"},"player":"Montez Sweat","print_run":{"$numberDouble":"99"},"purchase_date":"Thu Aug 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020","series":"Rookie Signatures","status":"Own","team":"Washington Football Team","type":"Auto","user":"jinky32@gmail.com","variation":"Base","year":"2019","userName":"jinky32"},{"_id":{"$oid":"5f94118c32d764f7ad2c6533"},"card_id":"cardid-1602670563767","brand":"Immaculate","card_number":{"$numberDouble":"19"},"career_stage":"Rookie Card","forTrade":"No","image_path":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/","manufacturer":"Panini","number":{"$numberDouble":"19"},"player":"Terry McLaurin","print_run":{"$numberDouble":"99"},"purchase_date":"Tue Aug 18 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020","series":"Rookie Patch Autographs","status":"Own","team":"Washington Football Team","type":"RPA","user":"jinky32@gmail.com","variation":"Base","year":"2019","userName":"jinky32"},{"_id":{"$oid":"5f94118d32d764f7ad2c6593"},"card_id":"cardid-1602670564059","brand":"National Treasures","card_number":{"$numberDouble":"187"},"career_stage":"Rookie Card","forTrade":"","image_path":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/","manufacturer":"Panini","number":{"$numberDouble":"1"},"player":"Terry McLaurin","print_run":{"$numberDouble":"10"},"purchase_date":"Sat Oct 03 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020","series":"Rookie Autograph Patch","status":"Own","team":"Washington Football Team","type":"RPA","user":"jinky32@gmail.com","variation":"Holo Gold","year":"2019","userName":"jinky32"},{"_id":{"$oid":"5f94118d32d764f7ad2c65f9"},"card_id":"cardid-1602670566267","brand":"National Treasures","card_number":{"$numberDouble":"187"},"career_stage":"Rookie Card","forTrade":"","image_path":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/","manufacturer":"Panini","number":{"$numberDouble":"5"},"player":"Terry McLaurin","print_run":{"$numberDouble":"10"},"purchase_date":"Thu Sep 24 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020","series":"Rookie Autograph Patch","status":"Own","team":"Washington Football Team","type":"RPA","user":"jinky32@gmail.com","variation":"Holo Gold","year":"2019","userName":"jinky32"},{"_id":{"$oid":"5f94118d32d764f7ad2c663f"},"card_id":"cardid-1602670566046","brand":"National Treasures","card_number":{"$numberDouble":"187"},"career_stage":"Rookie Card","forTrade":"No","image_path":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/","manufacturer":"Panini","number":{"$numberDouble":"8"},"player":"Terry McLaurin","print_run":{"$numberDouble":"10"},"purchase_date":"Sun Sep 06 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020","series":"Rookie Autograph Patch","status":"Own","team":"Washington Football Team","type":"RPA","user":"jinky32@gmail.com","variation":"Holo Gold","year":"2019","userName":"jinky32"}]
```

but my first log `console.log("TABLE IS UPDATED.." + this.context.ownedCards[0].brand);` causes the app to blow up with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'brand' of undefined`.

Can anyone help me understand why this is and how to resobve it?

To see this in action, go to https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-meadow-pvqdk - in the "Already a users? section first enter 'jinky32@gmail.com' in the email address, then head back to the homepage and enter 'tcctradingcardclub@gmail.com' into the same field.  The data does not change.  The relevant component is https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-meadow-pvqdk?file=/src/components/table.js

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Without seeing any relevant pieces of the code, I would suspect, your `context` array may have (for certain entries) no items. Solution could be as simple as [conditional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining): `this?.context?.ownedCards[0]?.brand`

Comment: Thanks both - I have added a functional codebox example.  Thanks for your time.  The relevant component is https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-meadow-pvqdk?file=/src/components/table.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that you're loading `ownedCards` *asynchronously*:

```js
  loadOwnedCardData = (url) => {
      ...
      // axios.get(...) is asynchronous!
      return axios
        .get(`${api}`)
        .then((result) => {
          // setState is also asynchronous!
          this.setState({
            ownedCards: result.data,
            ...
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          ...
        });
    }
  };
```

So when you try to read a value from the `ownedCards` array, it's `undefined`!

```js
// ownedCards is undefined until your request completes and setState commits the updated state.
console.log("TABLE IS UPDATED.." + this.context.ownedCards[0].brand);
```

To fix this, you can simply follow Yevgen Gorbunkov's advice and use the [`optional chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator:

```js
console.log("TABLE IS UPDATED.." + this.context.ownedCards[0]?.brand);
```

Another possible solution would be to track a `loading` state within your context which you can then use to determine whether or not `ownedCards` has properly loaded the data you require:

```js
loadOwnedCardData = (url) => {
      ...
      this.setState({ loadingOwnedCards: true });
      return axios
        .get(`${api}`)
        .then((result) => {
          this.setState({
            ownedCards: result.data,
            loadingOwnedCards: false,
            ...
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          ...
        });
    }
  };
```

```js
// You should still ensure that ownedCards isn't an empty array!
console.log("TABLE IS UPDATED.." + !this.context.loadingOwnedCards && this.context.ownedCards[0].brand);
```

Comment: Many thanks.  I'll mark your answer as correct because I can indeed access the value via `optional chaining`.  That still doesn't help me solve my problem, but that's because I think I'm asking the wrong question!